# Dell Inspiron 3650 adding old hard drive

Tags: dell-inspiron, dell-dimension

I have an old dimension E520 which has a power supply problem and no longer boots up but I have some data which I need to recover. I'm considering buying the Inpiron 3650 - would it be possible to add the hard drive from the old machine to the new system to transfer the files?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's definitely possible.
You can plug it to vacant SATA slot or just buy USB-SATA adapter, which is cheap as dirt and plug drive as external USB HDD.

Comment: If it works for you, please mark it as "Answer".

Comment: You forgot to mention that by using the built in SATA cables you will need to check to make sure enough power is going to the HD.

Comment: Too little won't make it work at all but too much will kill the hard drive and most likely the other one. You can also tell what voltage you will need by size. Thin ones (2.5 inch) will require 5V and nothing higher. While thick ones (3.5 inch) will need minimum 5V but mostly can handle up to around 9V